# Calling Microsoft Graph API to create an event, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I've been trying to call Microsoft Graph API for creating events, however I've not been able to do it.

**Context:** I have a Web MVC application (C#) already in production, with the "common" authentication method, reading a database of users. Recently the customer asked me the possibility to create Microsoft Teams Meetings from the application and also those created meetings have to be scheduled in the Microsoft Teams Calendar with the "Join" button to enter the meeting.

I already configured the API permissions, client secret and used the other properties like tenant, user id, etc from the Azure Portal, I'm sharing a screenshot of my configuration. I'm doing the "Get access on behalf of a user" process.

API Permissions:
[Permissions image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AllFU.png)

Taking the example of the authorize endpoint from the docs, of course I'm replacing the values with my own info

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
&state=12345
```

Here is my code to Receive the code once the user authorizes the permissions, I'm just storing the value in a static class for testing

```
public ActionResult ReceiveCode(string code)
{
    AuthenticationConfig.Code = code;
    //this.Code = code;
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Once I got the Auth code, I'm using it to create the event with the generated token, also I already verified that the token contains the permissions given in the Azure Portal.

This is the input for the /events endpoint

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new 
{ 
    subject = "Let's go for lunch",
    body = new 
    {
        contentType = "HTML",
        content = "Does noon work for you?"
    },
    start = new 
    {
        dateTime = "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
        timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time",
    },
    end = new 
    {
        dateTime = "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
        timeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    location = new 
    {
        displayName = "Harry's Bar",
    },
    attendees = new List<Attendee>()
    {
        new Attendee
        {
            EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
            {
                Address = "mymail@whatever.com",
                Name = "Foo Bar"
            },
            Type = AttendeeType.Required
        }
    },
    allowNewTimeProposals = true,
    isOnlineMeeting = true,
    onlineMeetingProvider = "teamsForBusiness",
});
```

This is the complete method, for the json value, please see the json above. I also tried with the "me" url but it does not work either.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OnlineMeeting()
{
    try
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var paramsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        paramsDictionary.Add("client_id",AuthenticationConfig.ClientId);
        paramsDictionary.Add("scope", "Calendars.ReadWrite");
        paramsDictionary.Add("code", AuthenticationConfig.Code);
        paramsDictionary.Add("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44379/Meeting/Reunion/ReceiveCode");
        paramsDictionary.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        paramsDictionary.Add("client_secret", AuthenticationConfig.ClientSecret);

        var url = string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/oauth2/v2.0/token", "tenant");

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, new FormUrlEncodedContent(paramsDictionary));
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonResponse) as JObject;
            var accessToken = jsonResult.GetValue("access_token").ToString();

            httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { });

            var defaultRequestHeaders = httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders;
            if (defaultRequestHeaders.Accept == null || !defaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Any(m => m.MediaType == "application/json"))
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            }
            defaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
            var data = new StringContent(json);

            response = await httpClient.PostAsync("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/events", data);
                
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Nice
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to call the web API: {response.StatusCode}");
                string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to call the web API: {response.StatusCode}");
            string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return View();
}
```

I'm able to the get the token, but when trying to create the event returns the next response.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource could not be discovered.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-08-31T22:58:18",
            "request-id": "c5c07afa-fa89-4948-a9f8-f80ca4cbafc3",
            "client-request-id": "c5c07afa-fa89-4948-a9f8-f80ca4cbafc3"
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Maybe the wrong endpoint?
Please, help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the user you are testing with have an active mailbox in Exchange Online or is the user mailbox on-premise? These two states can cause the error.

Comment: Also does this issue happen only for one user or all users?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by Mailbox in Exchange Online or on-premise, but I'll do some research about it. I've only tested with one user, the one I'm using for the Azure Portal account.

Comment: That user must have an exchange mailbox license for AAD account or outlook for Microsoft accounts. Please verify that.

Comment: Alright, I'll check it out, thanks.

Comment: Hello, I already asked to the administrator but I haven't received any response. However, I tried with the Graph Explorer and it worked the event creation. Not sure if that means the user I tested with has an Exchange Mailbox for AAD or Outlook for Microsoft Accounts. What do you think?

Comment: Both outlook or exchange mailboxes will allow creation of an event. Any user that returns 404 does have neither exchange nor outlook mailboxes activated

Comment: When you say mailbox, are you talking about the inbox? Where I receive my, let's say common emails (message from another account, password resets, advertisements). Cause if that the case, yes, the account has an outlook mailbox, and if that the case then my problem is related with another thing. Have you implemented microsoft graph api before?